# Issues with ggplotly within Shiny context

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly, geom-text

Using the code below, I could create the plot shown in the image. I am trying to fix some issues as follows:

1- How can I place the legend between title and plot. I would like to have the legend in a horizontal format rather than the current vertical form.

2- How can I bold, and center the plot title?

3- How can use different shapes in the geom_point function, depending on the "Disability" variable?

4- How can I rename the label so it reads "Age at Death" instead of the current name: "AgeatDeath"?

Thanks,

Nader

[image]

```
 IDD_line <-
  ggplot(IDD_plot) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = AgeatDeath, color = Disability), size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Year,
                 y = AgeatDeath,
                 color = Disability),
             size = 1.5,
             shape = 21) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2008, 2017, 1)) +
  labs(
    x = "Year",
    y = "Age at Death",
    caption = (""),
    face = "bold"
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(35, 80, 5)) +
  ggtitle(paste("Age of Death by Year (2008 to 2017)")) +
  theme(
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text = (blue.bold.10.text),
    legend.position = "top"
  )
output$IDD_plot <- renderPlotly(ggplotly(IDD_line) %>%
                                  config(displayModeBar = F))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bit harder than I initially anticipated. Maybe somebody else will come up with some better solutions, but here's what I have.

1. *How can I place the legend between title and plot. I would like to have the legend in a horizontal format rather than the current vertical form.*

You can do this in `layout` after call to `ggplotly`. To put into horizontal form, use `orientation = "h"`. If you specify `y = 1.2` this will go above the plot (if you just set `yanchor` at "top" this will go on the plot itself near the top).

In addition, you'll want to add extra margin so the legend does not overlap with the title. Use `margin` to set left, right, bottom, and top margins (`l`, `r`, `b`, and `t`).

```
layout(legend = list(x = 0, y = 1.2, orientation = "h"),
       margin = list(l = 50, r = 50, b = 100, t = 100)...
```

2. *How can I bold, and center the plot title?*

To bold the title, you can add HTML tags, such as `<b>title</b>` in `ggtitle`. To center the title, add that to `layout` as in #1, using `xanchor`:

```
layout(legend = list(x = 0, y = 1.2, orientation = "h"),
       margin = list(l = 50, r = 50, b = 100, t = 100),
       title = list(xanchor = "center", x = .5))
```

3. *How can use different shapes in the geom_point function, depending on the "Disability" variable?*

To get the shape to depend on "Disability", you will need `shape = Disability` in your aesthetic. The tricky part is that if you do this inside `aes` inside `geom_point`, you will get duplicate legends after converting to `ggplotly`. You can get around this with a separate `aes` outside of `geom_point`.

For more information see [this github issue comment](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/572#issuecomment-607354229).

4. *How can I rename the label so it reads "Age at Death" instead of the current name: "AgeatDeath"?*

One method is to use `text` in your `aes` and clarify your labels this way. This will include line breaks with `<br>`, `%d` for integer values, and `%s` for string (for Disability):

```
text = sprintf("Year: %d<br>Age at Death: %d<br>Disability: %s", 
               Year, AgeatDeath, Disability)
```

Then, in your `ggplotly` call, include `tooltip = "text"`.

So putting this all together, you have:

```
IDD_line <- ggplot(IDD_plot) +
  aes(color = Disability, 
      shape = Disability, 
      group = Disability, 
      text = sprintf("Year: %d<br>Age at Death: %d<br>Disability: %s", 
                     Year, AgeatDeath, Disability)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = AgeatDeath), size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Year,
                 y = AgeatDeath),
             size = 1.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2008, 2017, 1)) +
  labs(
    x = "Year",
    y = "Age at Death",
    caption = (""),
    face = "bold"
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(35, 80, 5)) +
  ggtitle(paste("<b>Age of Death by Year (2008 to 2017)</b>")) +
  theme(
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text = (blue.bold.10.text) #,
    #legend.position = "top"
  )
```

And,

```
output$IDD_plot <- renderPlotly(
    ggplotly(IDD_line, tooltip = "text") %>%
      config(displayModeBar = F) %>%
      layout(legend = list(x = 0, y = 1.2, orientation = "h"),
             margin = list(l = 50, r = 50, b = 100, t = 100),
             title = list(xanchor = "center", x = .5))
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is really helpful. However, I got the error of "invalid format '%d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects."

Comment: Instead of %d try %f for example